# how to create matrix in PHP with data from mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table in mysql, table "distance":

```
  id  | distance |          
  1   |    8     |  
  2   |    5     |    
  3   |    7     |
```

I want output such as:

```
8    5   7
8    5   7
8    5   7
```

How do I code it in php? Thanks, I'm a newbie in PHP.

Comment: you just echo the distance 3 times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

```
$tableRows[0]=array("id"=>1,"distance"=>8);
$tableRows[1]=array("id"=>2,"distance"=>5);
$tableRows[2]=array("id"=>3,"distance"=>7);
$counter=0;
foreach($tableRows as $tableRow)
{
    foreach($tableRows as $tableRow)
    {
        echo $tableRow["distance"]."\t";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/wUIoSb)

Comment: your well come,you can accept this answer if it is correct ;}

Comment: mr. ashkufaraz can you help me again. I found problem again.

Comment: I have a question and I alrady post in stackoverflow. this is my link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29329040/how-to-create-dynamic-matrix-in-php/. But, I not found answer for my question. Please help me

Comment: thank's for respond mr.ashkufaraz. I am sorry. How combine your code with my code using for. And How to connect your code with database mysql? hee.. :)

Comment: I've compile/run this code ,. end result become array : 1 2 3 1 0 8 6 2 8 0 9 3 6 9 0 .

Comment: this is correct?instead `$tableRow` use $citry from database

Comment: no, this is sir. I want end result in matrix, this result in array. :)

Comment: so use this `$from = $cityDist['id_city_a'];
    $to = $cityDist['id_city_b'];
    $dist = $cityDist['distance'];
    $distMatrix[$from][$to] = $dist;`

Comment: Iam sory,.. I can't data above connect to mysql. it's difficult, I am newbie in php