# How to create dynamic matrix in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table "city" in my database:

```
|id |id_city_a |id_city_b|distance|
|1  |1         | 1   | 0      |
|2  |1         | 2   | 8      |
|3  |1         | 3   | 6      |
|4  |2         | 1   | 8      |
|5  |2         | 2   | 0      |
|6  |2         | 3   | 9      |
|7  |3         | 1   | 6      |
|8  |3         | 2   | 9      |
|9  |3         | 3   | 0      |
```

I want the end result to be in a matrix, such as:

|   | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 1 | 0 | 8 | 6 |
| 2 | 8 | 0 | 9 |
| 3 | 6 | 9 | 0 |

This is my code :

`function    random()  
{  
    include('config/koneksi.php');  
    $result = mysql_query("select * from temp_hasil");  
    $n =mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM temp_hasil"));

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $n; $i++)
    {

     for ($j = 1; $j <= $n; $j++)    
        {

            $rows = mysql_fetch_array($result);
            $this->table[$i][$j] = $i == $j ? INF :  $rows['id'];

        }
    }
}

function    __toString()  
{  
    $str = '<table class="table table-bordered" id="tableInput"> <tbody>';  
    $str .= '<tr><td></td>';  
    foreach ($this->table as $rowName => $row)  
    {  
        $str .= "<td>$rowName</td>";  
    }  
    $str .= '</tr>';  
foreach ($this->table as $rowName => $row)  
{  
    $str .= "<tr><td>$rowName</td>";  
    foreach ($row as $columnName => $value)  
    {  
        $str .= "<td>";  
        $str .=  
            '<input class="form-control" type="text" value="' . $value . '" name="table[' . $rowName . '][' .
            $columnName . ']" requied' . ($columnName == $rowName ? ' disabled' : '') . '>';
        $str .= "</td>";
    }
    $str .= '</tr>';
}
$str .= '</tbody></table>';
return $str;
}

}
$str .= '</tr>';  
foreach ($this->table as $rowName => $row)  
{  
    $str .= "<tr><td>$rowName</td>";  
    foreach ($row as $columnName => $value)  
    {    
        $str .= "<td>";  
        $str .=  
            '<input class="form-control" type="text" value="' . $value . '" name="table[' . $rowName . '][' .
            $columnName . ']" requied' . ($columnName == $rowName ? ' disabled' : '') . '>';
        $str .= "</td>";    
    }      
    $str .= '</tr>';    
}  
$str .= '</tbody></table>';    
return $str;    
}`

`

How do I code it in php? please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make city_a index completely different from city_b index so it is easy to check.

```
// generate a two-dimensional matrix in here
$distMatrix = array();

foreach($tableRows as $cityDist) {
    $from = $cityDist['id_city_a'];
    $to = $cityDist['id_city_b'];
    $dist = $cityDist['distance'];

    $distMatrix[$from][$to] = $dist;
}
```

Display as an HTML Table...

```
echo '<table border="1">';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<td>', '#', '</td>';
foreach(array_keys(current($distMatrix)) as $city_b) { // city_b headings
   echo '<td>', $city_b ,'</td>';
}
echo '</tr>';

foreach(array_keys($distMatrix) as $city_a) { // need the city_a as row index
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>', $city_a, '</td>'; // city_a ad
    foreach(array_keys($distMatrix[$city_a]) as $city_b) { // need the city_b as column index
        echo '<td>', $distMatrix[$city_a][$city_b], '</td>'; // distance from the matrix;
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Test data - used data from @ashkufaraz

```
// changed the city ids so we can easily see city_a and city_b
$tableRows[0]=array("id"=>1, "id_city_a"=>1, "id_city_b"=>11, "distance"=>0);
$tableRows[1]=array("id"=>2, "id_city_a"=>1, "id_city_b"=>12, "distance"=>8);
$tableRows[2]=array("id"=>3, "id_city_a"=>1, "id_city_b"=>13, "distance"=>6);
$tableRows[3]=array("id"=>4, "id_city_a"=>2, "id_city_b"=>11, "distance"=>8);
$tableRows[4]=array("id"=>5, "id_city_a"=>2, "id_city_b"=>12, "distance"=>0);
$tableRows[5]=array("id"=>6, "id_city_a"=>2, "id_city_b"=>13, "distance"=>9);
$tableRows[6]=array("id"=>7, "id_city_a"=>3, "id_city_b"=>11, "distance"=>6);
$tableRows[7]=array("id"=>8, "id_city_a"=>3, "id_city_b"=>12, "distance"=>9);
$tableRows[8]=array("id"=>9, "id_city_a"=>3, "id_city_b"=>13, "distance"=>0);
```

Output:

```
#   11  12  13
1   0   8   6
2   8   0   9
3   6   9   0
```

Comment: how to connect this array with database?

Answer (score 1):

try like this

[Online Demo](https://ideone.com/zQdNoZ)

```
$tableRows[0]=array("id"=>1,"id_city_a"=>1,"id_city_b"=>1,"distance"=>0);
$tableRows[1]=array("id"=>2,"id_city_a"=>1,"id_city_b"=>2,"distance"=>8);
$tableRows[2]=array("id"=>3,"id_city_a"=>1,"id_city_b"=>3,"distance"=>6);
$tableRows[3]=array("id"=>4,"id_city_a"=>2,"id_city_b"=>1,"distance"=>8);
$tableRows[4]=array("id"=>5,"id_city_a"=>2,"id_city_b"=>2,"distance"=>0);
$tableRows[5]=array("id"=>6,"id_city_a"=>2,"id_city_b"=>3,"distance"=>9);
$tableRows[6]=array("id"=>7,"id_city_a"=>3,"id_city_b"=>1,"distance"=>6);
$tableRows[7]=array("id"=>8,"id_city_a"=>3,"id_city_b"=>2,"distance"=>9);
$tableRows[8]=array("id"=>9,"id_city_a"=>3,"id_city_b"=>3,"distance"=>0);

$counter=0;
$result=array();
foreach($tableRows as $tableRow)
{
    $result[$tableRow["id_city_a"]][$tableRow["id_city_b"]]=array("id_city_a"=>$tableRow["id_city_a"],"id_city_b"=>$tableRow["id_city_b"],"distance"=>$tableRow["distance"] );
}
```

now in `$result[cityA][cityB]=distance`

get unique_id_city_a for column

```
$unique_id_city_a = array_unique(array_map(function ($i) { return $i['id_city_a']; }, $tableRows));
echo "\t";
foreach($unique_id_city_a as $R)
{
    echo $R."\t";
}
echo "\n";
```

get unique_id_city_b for rows

```
$unique_id_city_b = array_unique(array_map(function ($i) { return $i['id_city_b']; }, $tableRows));


foreach($result as $R1)
{       
    echo $unique_id_city_b[$counter++]."\t";
    foreach($R1 as $R2)
    {
        echo $R2["distance"]."\t";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

Comment: mr. ashkufaraz,.. I have new question. this is link my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29382428/how-to-query-from-two-tables/29383248#29383248. please help me

Comment: this question is closed

Comment: how generate end result?i does not understand

Comment: Thank's you mr.Ashkufaraz. :) who have helped me