# how to query from two tables?

Tags: mysql

I have two table:

1. Table 'temp_hsl'

```
|id|kota_a|  
|41| 1    |
|42| 2    |
```

2. Table 'jarak kota'

```
|id|kota_a|kota_b | jarak|
|1 |1     |1      | 0    |
|2 |1     |2      | 2    |
|3 |1     |3      | 3    |
|4 |2     |1      | 2    |
|5 |2     |2      | 0    |
|6 |2     |3      | 3    |
|7 |3     |1      | 3    |
|8 |3     |2      | 3    |
|9 |3     |3      | 0    |
```

I want end result:

```
|id|kota_a|kota_b | jarak|
|1 |1     |1      | 0    |
|2 |1     |2      | 2    |
|3 |2     |1      | 2    |
|4 |2     |2      | 0    |
```

The result above is based on a relation table with table temp_hsl. 
 How do it with command mysql? I 've tried , but the results of its query looping continues.

Comment: Read up on JOINS http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins

Comment: This question is about extremely basic programming concepts, and thus it is showing low effort from the asker. Also, it has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Oh and moreover, it's a duplicated, that can also be answered by google. this is an example of which questions ARE NOT WELCOME in stackoverflow.

Comment: for all : I'm sorry... And @STT LCU : I'm sorry too

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you are asking, but you should be able to do something like:
select * from tableX where fieldX in (select fieldX from tableY)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong you can alias your table first and use the below SQL Query. it may help you to solved your query

SELECT A.id, A.j
FROM jarak_kota A
INNER JOIN temp_hsl B ON A.kota_a = B.kota_a
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: You have to add where condition like kota_b IN (1,2)  Use this SELECT A.id, A.kota_a, A.kota_b, A.jarak
FROM jarak A
INNER JOIN temp_hsl B ON A.kota_a = B.kota_a 
WHERE A.kota_b
IN ( 1, 2 )
LIMIT 0 , 30  .... You can find the same records which you want

Comment: I've tried this code: SELECT A.id, A.kota_a, A.kota_b, A.jarak FROM jarak A INNER JOIN temp_hsl B ON A.kota_a = B.kota_a WHERE A.kota_a IN ( 1, 2 ) LIMIT 0 , 30. but this is not the expected results. Do you any solution? :)

Comment: @Ashmik please do not help further this user. This question is lowering the quality of the site. Just let it be, it's going to be closed. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this, just edit @Ashmik's answer should work fine if you don't edit your question again.

> SELECT A.id, A.kota_a, A.kota_b, A.jarak FROM jarak_kota A INNER JOIN
>   temp_hsl B ON A.kota_a = B.kota_a LIMIT 0 , 30